# spread HTML elements randomly over a div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I wish to create something like a virtual forest.

I have:

- fixed size div, where I wish to spread the trees
- Random number of trees (each tree is a PNG)
- small square div in the center that should be kept clear of trees

How can I spread the trees so they:

- Wont overlap each other
- Wont get into the central div
- Calculate their size (css) so all trees will fit into the div

Thanks

**More info as requested:**

- All the tree images has same dimension
- Container div has a fixed dimensions of 500x300 px
- Small central div has a fixed dimensions of 30x30 px
- The png native resolution is 60x60 px

I created the following php script, but it does not handle the empty location nor its accurate in fitting the images into the div:

```
$forest1 = null;
for ($a=1; $a < 201; $a++) {

    // width * height (500*280)
    $total_area_in_pixels = 140000;
    $total_elements = 200;
    $area_per_object = $total_area_in_pixels / $total_elements;
    $element_height = round (sqrt($area_per_object) / 100 * 70);

    $random_margin = rand(0, $element_height / 5);
    $tree_type = rand(1,4);
    $style = "height: {$element_height}px; margin: {$random_margin}px;";
    $forest1 .= "<img src='images/trees/tree{$tree_type}.png' alt='{$a}' title='tree' style='{$style}'>\n";
}
```

Comment: missing info. they're not overlapping so is this an overhead view? are the trees the same size? is the div a fixed size? what size is the small square? if we are to calculate the tree size after picking a random amount what are the limits on the size of the trees?

Comment: JavaScript has solution for everything but please precisely elaborate your problem.

Comment: what did you try ? please post some code

Answer (score 2):

You need to figure out how you want to do the positioning first.  You can either set the trees absolutely based on the div parent as a container, or you can position the trees absolutely based on the entire page as a container.

To use the parent as a container, you would do this:
Set the div to position: relative.  Write javascript to create IMG elements and then set their position to 'absolute'.  Make sure that when you create the elements you create them as child elements of the DIV you want to contain them.

TO use the page as a container, you would do this:
Write javascript to create IMG elements and set their position to 'absolute'.  Don't bother making them child elements of the DIV because it doesn't matter.  Use jQuery or a basic javascript test to find out the exact page position of the container div.  Everytime you place a tree, you will need to calculate its position with respect to the container div.

Position trees basically like this:
Write a simple algorithm to generate random x and y coordinate pairs to position each element and do so.  Then check each tree's position and width and height against the square area you don't want to be covered.  If you find a tree in that area, either move it some to get it out of the area, or delete it.  Just make sure to remember that if you're positioning absolutely within the whole page, you'll always have to add or subtract the page container position as an offste to get the trees where you want them on the page.

That should be enough to get you started.

Comment: You don't need to worry about subtracting the container position when positioning absolutely if you give the container `position: relative` (and are putting them inside the container in the dom not just visually)